# Why react js cannot find my exported modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run my react app, the console said

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/login/index.js
Attempted import error: 'Login' is not exported from './login'.
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
├── index.js
├── login.js
└── register.js
```

index.js file:

```
export { Login } from "./login";
export { Register } from "./register";
```

login.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import loginImg from "../../login.svg";



class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            // correct code
        )
    }
}


export default Login;
```

At first, I thought it was due to typo or sth like that, but I checked the spelling and syntax and still confused by the error. Really want to get some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `export default` but your `index.js` does not import the default export. Change to:

```
export { default as Login } from "./login";
export { default as Register } from "./register"
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is your Login component has default export. And you imported it as named export.

Your import statement must be

```js
import Login from './login'
```

```js
import { default as Login } from './login'
```

Or you should export your Login component as

```js
export { Login }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you export anything as default then you have to import it as

`import Login from "./login";`

not

`import { Login } from "./login";`

Answer (score 2):

if you are exporting multiple functions or components you can import like

```
import { Login } from "./login";
```

But in your case you are exporting a single component itself.  So you can import like

```
import Login from "./login";
```

since `Login` is the only thing that is being exported from `login.js`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should remove {} over your component.
replace this:

```js
import {Login} from "./login"
```

with this:

```js
import Login from "./login"
```

Answer (score 0):

**If it happens** when you use **Jest to run tests**, maybe this helps you:

In my case was because I started the command "npm run test" and later created a new JS file in a new folder (data/heroes.js), and it was not finding that new file, showing this error:

```
Cannot find module '../data/heroes' from 'src/base/08-imp-exp.js'
```

But VsCode editor detected imports and exports correctly, so I restarted the terminal instance that was running the tests, and **it worked** !

***Restart the tests terminal !***

Comment: Sometimes, even restarting doesn't work. Just keep doing it until it works.